# Reformatting for Angular style guide 1.5

Tags: javascript, angularjs, atmosphere

I am using the Angular [spyboost](https://github.com/spyboost/angular-atmosphere) utility wrapper. I am trying to reformat it for this [angular 1 style guide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide).  I'm having a hard time with parts of it. I think I have most of it correct but the angular.forEach function is throwing me off. I am and am getting an error `Expected '{' and instead saw 'result'. Could someone help me please ?

```
 angular
    .module('myMod')
    .factory('MyService');
MyService.$inject = ['$rootScope', 'atmosphereService', 'atmosphere'];

function MyService ($rootScope, atmosphere) {
    return {
        subscribe: subscribe,
        getMessage: getMessage
    };

    function subscribe (r) {
        var responseParameterDelegateFunctions = ['onOpen', 'onClientTimeout', 'onReopen', 'onMessage', 'onClose', 'onError'];
        var delegateFunctions = responseParameterDelegateFunctions;
        var result = {};

        delegateFunctions.push('onTransportFailure');
        delegateFunctions.push('onReconnect');

        angular.forEach(r, function (value, property) {
            if (typeof value === 'function' && delegateFunctions.indexOf(property) >= 0) {
                if (responseParameterDelegateFunctions.indexOf(property) >= 0)
                    **result[property] = function (response) {**
                        $rootScope.$apply(function () {
                            r[property](response);
                        });
                    };
                else if (property === 'onTransportFailure')
                    result.onTransportFailure = function (errorMsg, request) {
                        $rootScope.$apply(function () {
                            r.onTransportFailure(errorMsg, request);
                        });
                    };
                else if (property === 'onReconnect')
                    result.onReconnect = function (request, response) {
                        $rootScope.$apply(function () {
                            r.onReconnect(request, response);
                        });
                    };
            } else
                result[property] = r[property];
        });

        function getMessage () {
            var vm = this;
            var request = {
                url: '/chat',
                contentType: 'application/json',
                transport: 'websocket',
                reconnectInterval: 5000,
                enableXDR: true,
                timeout: 60000
            };

            request.onMessage(response); {
                vm.$apply (function () {
                    vm.model.message = atmosphere.util.parseJSON(response.responseBody);
                });
            }
        }
        return atmosphere.subscribe(result);
    }

}

})(window.angular);
```

Comment: Looks like you have the closing of an IIFE but don't see the opening `(function(){` doesn't appear to be the error you see but seems like the copy/paste is incomplete.

Comment: Looks like subscribe doesn't close before getMessage is defined as well, count up for every { and down for every } you should end up at 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (responseParameterDelegateFunctions.indexOf(property) >= 0)
```

is missing its curly braces?

```
if (responseParameterDelegateFunctions.indexOf(property) >= 0) {
    result[property] = function (response) {
           $rootScope.$apply(function () {
                    r[property](response);
                });
           };
}
else if (property === 'onTransportFailure') {
     result.onTransportFailure = function (errorMsg, request) {
         $rootScope.$apply(function () {
             r.onTransportFailure(errorMsg, request);
          });
      };
}
else if (property === 'onReconnect') {
     result.onReconnect = function (request, response) {
         $rootScope.$apply(function () {
              r.onReconnect(request, response);
         });
     };
}
```

Comment: Yep, it was missing that curly brace. I still get the same error though.   How should the IFFE look?

Comment: Actually, it looks like all the if statements inside the first one are missing their curly braces.

Comment: Regarding the IIFE, count how many open brackets and closed you have... there's one too many closed brackets. you should add 
    (function(){
to line one to complete the Immediately Invoked Function Expression